# How to automatically deduce child class member type?

Tags: typescript, types

Consider this code:

```
class test
{
    test: {test: string[]}
}

class so extends test
{
    test = {test: []}
}
```

If we enable noImplicitAny the error message we got is the following:

> Object literal's property 'test' implicitly has an '`any[]`' type.

How can I make the type auto deduces from the parent class?

Answer (score 0):

Second class declares the 'test' again. To initialize parent field move assignment statement to constructor

```
class test
{
    test: {test: string[]}
}

class so extends test
{
  constructor() { 
    super();

    this.test = { test: [] };

  }
}
```